# Why the Qunit counter in this test never reaches the target value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, qunit

I'm sitting on a Qunit test and having trouble to follow what's happening. The test if from jQuery Mobile's listview.filter extension.

I'm clueless as to how the variable `_refreshCornersCount` ever reaches the value of `3`.

Here is the part in question.

```
module( "Custom search filter", {
    setup: function() {
        var self = this;
          // initially set to 0
          this._refreshCornersCount = 0;
          this._refreshCornersFn = 
            $.mobile.filterbar.prototype._addFirstLastClasses;

        this.startTest = function() {
          return this._refreshCornersCount === 1;
        };

        // _refreshCorners is the last method called in the filter loop
        // so we count the number of times _refreshCorners gets invoked 
        // to stop the test
        $.mobile.filterbar.prototype._addFirstLastClasses = function() {
            // increase by 1
            self._refreshCornersCount += 1;
            self._refreshCornersFn.apply( this, arguments );
            if ( self.startTest() ) {
                start();
            }
        }
    },
    teardown: function() {
        $.mobile.filterbar.prototype._refreshCorners = this._refreshCornersFn;
    }
});

asyncTest( "Custom filterCallback iterates on all list elements",
    function(){
        var listPage = $( "#search-customfilter-test" ),
          filterCallbackCount = 0,
          expectedCount = 2 * listPage.find("li").length;
        expect( 1 );

        this.startTest = function() {
            // trigger once _refreshCornersCount reaches 3
            if ( this._refreshCornersCount === 3 ) {
            equal(
                filterCallbackCount,
                expectedCount,
                "filterCallback called "+ expectedCount +" times"
            );
        }
        // return true/false
        return this._refreshCornersCount === 3;
    }

    $.testHelper.pageSequence( [

        ...
        // triggers a change,
        // which will triggers a filter loop
        listPage.find( "input" ).val( "at" ).trigger( "change" );
        listPage.find( "input" ).val( "atw" ).trigger( "change" );
        }
    ]);
});
```

I left out some code from the test, because the necessary parts are all there.

On my machine, the test never triggers, because `this._refreshCornersCount` is set to `0` and then increase 2x with the two input changes, each triggering a filter loop. So all parameters (including the one I'm testing for) are correct, only the test never fires, because `this._refreshCornersCount = 2`

**Question**:
I'm sitting on this for a while now... maybe I'm missing something obvious, so: Is there a technical way for `this._refreshCornersCount` to reach the value of `3` from the above code snippet only?

**EDIT**:
The test is a test from jQuery Mobile, specifically the listview filter extension. You can find the test [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/tests/integration/listview/listview_core.js#L657)

**EDIT:**:
So here is the full code of my test. Note I'm doing the same setup as in JQM.

```
module( "Custom search filter", {
    setup: function() {
        var self = this;
            this._refreshCornersCount = 0;
            this._refreshCornersFn = $.mobile.filterbar.prototype._addFirstLastClasses;
            this.startTest = function() {
                return this._refreshCornersCount === 1;
            };

        // _refreshCorners is the last method called in the filter loop
        // so we count the number of times _refreshCorners gets invoked to stop the test
        $.mobile.filterbar.prototype._addFirstLastClasses = function() {
            self._refreshCornersCount += 1;
            self._refreshCornersFn.apply( this, arguments );
            if ( self.startTest() ) {
                start();
            }
        }
    },
    teardown: function() {
        $.mobile.filterbar.prototype._refreshCorners = this._refreshCornersFn;
    }
});

asyncTest( "Custom filterCallback should cause iteration on all list elements", function(){
    var listPage = $( "#search-customfilter-test" ),
        filterCallbackCount = 0,
        expectedCount = 2 * listPage.find("li").length;
    expect( 1 );

    this.startTest = function() {
    // XXX NOTE: changed this to 2x, because two changes, trigger 2x _onKeyUp
    // and 2x addFirstLastClasses. I never reach 3 with the code as-is
    if ( this._refreshCornersCount === 2 ) {
        equal( filterCallbackCount, expectedCount, "filterCallback should be called exactly "+ expectedCount +" times" );
    }
    return this._refreshCornersCount === 2;
}

$.testHelper.pageSequence( [
    function(){
        //reset for relative url refs
        $.mobile.changePage( home );
    },

    function() {
        $.mobile.changePage( "#search-customfilter-test" );
    },

    function() {
        // set the listview instance callback
        listPage.find( "ul" ).filterbar( "option", "filterCallback", function( text, searchValue, item ) {
            filterCallbackCount += 1;

            return text.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf( searchValue ) === -1;
        });

        // trigger a change in the search filter
        listPage.find( "input" ).val( "at" ).trigger( "change" );
        listPage.find( "input" ).val( "atw" ).trigger( "change" );

        }
    ]);
});
...
```

Comment: nope. :-( You have an idea? It's an offical test from jQuery Mobile - see [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/tests/integration/listview/listview_core.js#L657). I have no clue how it reaches a value of 3...

Comment: Honestly, I haven't used qunit before, but I'm interested. I'll set a bounty.

Comment: Are you sure the test is correct?

Comment: @Stijn: yup. See edit above.

Comment: if the answer below is correct, you owe me 50+ rep lol

Comment: @Omar I don't know if my answer is correct, but it makes sense I think :)

Comment: @Stijn I hope it's correct; I cant decide on behalf of the OP :)

Comment: @frequent I'm clueless, sorry. Logging the value before `this._refreshCornersCount === 2` prints 1 through 5, logging it before `this._refreshCornersCount === 3` stops at 2. Hopefully someone else can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

The function is called at the end of each cycle. Before the call of

```
listPage.find( "input" ).val( "at" ).trigger( "change" );
```

is already invoked once. With the previus line it comes the second time, and with the last line

```
listPage.find( "input" ).val( "atw" ).trigger( "change" );
```

the third. Hence,

```
this._refreshCornersCount === 3
```

Hope this helps.